# undefined reference to `cvGetOptimalDFTSize'

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, g++, arm

I am working with Opencv-2.1 on arm-linux. I am using arm-linux-g++ compiler. I ran in to a strange error during linking. Before talking about the error, I will post my make commands

```
CC = arm-linux-g++
COMPILEFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -c -O2 -I./

OUT_DLL = libLensFinder.so
DLL_FLAGS = -shared -o
OBJS = SegmentRegions.o
OBJS2 = EdgeDetection.o
OBJS3 = AnalyseRegions.o
OBJS4 = global.o
LINK_FLAGS = -L./ -lLensFinder
LINK_FLAGS_2 = -L./ -lTwoX
INCPATH    = -I/home/zwang/ravi/opencv_include21/opencv/  -I.

all : 
$(CC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) $(INCPATH) global.cpp -o global.o
$(CC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) $(INCPATH) EdgeDetection.cpp -o EdgeDetection.o
$(CC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) $(INCPATH) SegmentRegions.cpp -o SegmentRegions.o
$(CC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) $(INCPATH) AnalyseRegions.cpp -o AnalyseRegions.o
$(CC) $(OBJS) $(OBJS2) $(OBJS3) $(OBJS4) $(DLL_FLAGS) ./$(OUT_DLL) -L/home/zwang/ravi/opencv_include21/lib -lcvaux -lcxcore -lhighgui -lcv -lml -lcxts -lrt

$(CC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) $(INCPATH) sample.cpp
#$(CC) $(LINK_FLAGS) sample.o -o sample 
$(CC) $(LINK_FLAGS) $(LINK_FLAGS_2) sample.o -o sample
```

Everything works fine till the end. During the last command i.e., while creating executable file I am getting the following error.

```
arm-linux-g++ -L./ -lLensFinder -L./ -lTwoX sample.o -o sample
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `spotrs_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `cvGetOptimalDFTSize'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dgels_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dgelsd_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dgesdd_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `cvMulSpectrums'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `sgesdd_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `sgetri_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `cvDFT'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dgesv_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dsyevr_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `sgels_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `spotrf_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `sgetrf_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dpotrf_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dpotri_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `sgesv_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `ssyevr_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dpotrs_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `sgelsd_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `spotri_'
.//libLensFinder.so: undefined reference to `dgetri_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Two of the undefined references are `cvMulSpectrums' and`cvGetOptimalDFTSize', which I guess is due to opencv. And I have no clue on other undefined reference. I think I have linked every library. But still can't understand how to solve this. Any suggestions? FYI, the code is working on visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those symbols are defined in the `libopencv_core` library file.

Notice how the command  `arm-linux-g++ -L./ -lLensFinder -L./ -lTwoX sample.o -o sample` doesn't  link **sample** with any opencv library, so it makes sense that the linking process complains about it.

You probably should adjust your build to do something like:

```
arm-linux-g++ sample.o -o sample -L./ -lLensFinder -L./ -lTwoX -L/home/zwang/ravi/opencv_include21/lib -lcvaux -lcxcore -lhighgui -lcv -lml -lcxts -lrt
```

Comment: the libraries you're recommending, - well, they're not dead, but they definitely smell like opencv1.1

Comment: Hello, I understand what you are saying. However, I'm not recommending anything besides what the OP stated in the question. You might want to add an answer pointing that out, I think it's important.

Comment: @karlphillip . Thanks for the solution. Yes, you are right. It works. I observed sports_, dgels_ etc belongs to 3rd party lapack. I linked that library too. And it works fine. Thanks a lot